# Problema con php y Sql Server (No se insertan los datos)

Tags: php, html, sql

Trabajo con un servidor en el cual quiero insertar datos pero no sucede.

Lo que pasa es que en localhost si funciona pero este mismo proyecto que tengo en el servidor no funciona.

Este mismo trabajo en localhost funciona correctamente y asi como esta pase el codigo al servidor y ahora no funciona.

La conexion no es ya que muestra datos que ya estan en la base de datos y algunas tablas que ya contienen datos.

Lo unico que no jala es insertar datos.

Utilizo php y SQL server

Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php 
include 'conexion.php';

$conexion = conexion(); 

$consulta = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO dbo.GRUPALES(CLAVE_GRUPAL, NOMBRE_GRUPAL, FECHA_REGISTRO, HORA_REGISTRO, RPE_RESPONSABLE, FECHA_GRUPAL, VALOR_GRUPAL)VALUES(:claveGrupal, :nombreGrupal ,GETDATE(), GETDATE(), :responsableRPEGrupal, :fechaDelGrupal, :valorGrupal)");

$consulta  -> bindParam(':claveGrupal', $claveGrupal);
$consulta  -> bindParam(':nombreGrupal', $nombreGrupal);
$consulta  -> bindParam(':responsableRPEGrupal', $responsableRPEGrupal);
$consulta  -> bindParam(':fechaDelGrupal', $fechaDelGrupal);
$consulta  -> bindParam(':valorGrupal', $valorGrupal);

$claveGrupal = $_POST['claveGrupal'];
$nombreGrupal = $_POST['nombreGrupal'];
$responsableRPEGrupal = $_POST['responsableRPEGrupal'];
$fechaDelGrupal = $_POST['fechaDelGrupal'];
$valorGrupal = $_POST['valorGrupal'];

$consulta->execute();

$conexion=null;
?>
```

Las unica diferencia con este codigo al original es el  dbo.GRUPALES lo cambie por T.GRUPALES ya que eso es del schema que asi esta en el servidor.

Otra cosa que sucede es que en la base de datos no tengo permisos de owner no se si eso tenga algo que ver ya que si puede insertar datos desde SQL server.

Comment: Que no te falta un `execute()`?

Comment: Cierto me falto ponerlo pero igual sigue el mismo error

Comment: Si no pones el error que sale en el servidor, poco podremos hacer por ayudarte...

Comment: Seria genial que postees el error como tal y tambien la clase "conexion.php"

Comment: no tengo ningun error en el servidor no me mandan nada de errores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre el problema espero que mi solucion le ayude a alguien que llegue a tener el mismo error al parecer cuando las tablas se movieron del servidor local al servidor externo esto ocasiono que las llaves primarias se eliminara al igual que las llaves foraneas y los id se pusieran como no incrementables.

Osea simplemente se creo una tabla normal y sencilla.

No se por que paso esto pero ese fue el error.

Answer (score 0):

Primero estas enviando los valores a tu declaración y luego los estas asignando, deberías primero intentar asignar los valores y luego enviarlos a la declaración... así:

```
<?php

    $consulta = $conexion->prepare($insertar_sql_aqui);

    $valor1 = $_POST['valor1'];
    $valor2 = $_POST['valor2'];
    $valor3 = $_POST['valor3'];

    $consulta->bindParam(':valor1', $valor1);
    $consulta->bindParam(':valor2', $valor2);
    $consulta->bindParam(':valor3', $valor3);

    //O en caso de que no quieras hacer tantas lineas puedes hacerlo con un ciclo... asi

    foreach($_POST as $indice => $post) {
        $consulta->bindParam(':'.$indice, $post);
    }

    // Ejecutas la consulta
    $consulta->execute(); 

    // Y al final destruyes la conexion
    $conexion=null;

?>
```

Comment: Ahora lo checo y te mantengo al tanto!

Comment: No sigue sin insertar los datos a la tabla